# setOnItemLongClickListener and setOnItemClickListener on the same class

Tags: java, android, android-activity, onclicklistener, onlongclicklistener

My issue issue is this one: When I press long click on item, I have two views which appears.

See below my code for java class. PLease help.

mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MyGoodsActivity.this, CurrentActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putLong(Record.BUNDLE_SHOP_ID, mShopId);
            bundle.putLong(Record.BUNDLE_the_ID, mGoodsAdapter.getItemId(position));
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            MyGoodsActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        }



    });

    mListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {



        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {




            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyGoodsActivity.this);
            dialog.setTitle(R.string.tip);
            dialog.setMessage(R.string.info_confirm_delete_this_item);
            dialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    MyDB db = new MyDB(MyGoodsActivity.this);
                    db.deleteGoodsById(mGoodsAdapter.getItemId(position));
                    refreshListgoods();
                }
            });
            dialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.ko, null);
            dialog.show();
            return false;
        }
    }


    );
```

Answer (score 1):

After analyse my code I have juste return true for resolve my issue.

```
            dialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.ko, null);
        dialog.show();
        return true;
    }
```